# AngularJS ng-focus and ng-blur not recognized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, input

I have read that AngularJS should let you use `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` as default controllers in an input tag. However, when I use them it gives me that...

> Namespace ng-focus is not bound...

I am using AngularJS 1.4.3, which I believe should be the latest version.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="input-boxes" ng-controller="formController">
    <form name="Form" ng-submit="submitForm()">
        <div class="required">
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="{{messages.inputEmail | langFilter}}" class="input-style" ng-model="inputs.email" ng-minlength="3" ng-pattern="form.pattern" required>
            <p class="error" ng-show="Form.user.$error.pattern && Form.user.$touched">&nbsp;{{messages.errorPattern | langFilter}}</p>
            <p class="error" ng-show="checkAccount">&nbsp;{{messages.errorAccount | langFilter}}</p>
            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="inputs.password" placeholder="{{messages.inputPassword | langFilter}}" class="input-style" ng-focus: "">
        </div>
```

The reason why I want to use `ng-focus/blur`, is because I want to set the `$touched` to false if the password field is selected.
Thank you!

Comment: Your error is that you have `ng-focus:` instead of `ng-focus=`. Within XML, namespaces occur before a colon, so it must be interpreting your statement as trying to use a namespace that is not bound within the document. Michelem has a good solution for what you want, though.

Comment: yup, I am an idiot :D

Answer (score -1):

Use `ng-focus` and tell it to update `Form.user.$touched` to `false`:

```
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="inputs.password" placeholder="{{messages.inputPassword | langFilter}}" class="input-style" ng-focus="Form.user.$touched = false">
```

Comment: problem is it gives me 'Attribute ng-focus not allowed here...'